# Running two instances of MirrorMaker 2.0 halting data replication for newer topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

We tried below scenario using mirror-maker 2.0 and want to know if output of second scenario is expected.

**Scenario 1.) We ran single mirror-maker 2.0 instance using the below properties and start command.**

```
clusters=a,b
tasks.max=10
a.bootstrap.servers=kf-test-cluster-a:9092
a.config.storage.replication.factor=1
a.offset.storage.replication.factor=1
a.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
a.status.storage.replication.factor=1
b.bootstrap.servers=kf-test-cluster-b:9092
b.config.storage.replication.factor=1
b.offset.storage.replication.factor=1
b.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
b.status.storage.replication.factor=1
a->b.checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=1
a->b.emit.checkpoints.enabled=true
a->b.emit.hearbeats.enabled=true
a->b.enabled=true
a->b.groups=group1|group2|group3
a->b.heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=1
a->b.offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=1
a->b.refresh.groups.interval.seconds=30
a->b.refresh.topics.interval.seconds=10
a->b.replication.factor=2
a->b.sync.topic.acls.enabled=false
a->b.topics=.*
```

**Start command**: /usr/bin/connect-mirror-maker.sh connect-mirror-maker.properties &

**Verification**: Created new topic "test" on source cluster(a), produced data to topic on source cluster and ran consumer on target-cluster(b),topic "a.test" to verify data replication.

**Observation**: Worked fine as expected.

**Scenario 2.) Ran one more instance of MirrorMaker 2.0 using the same properties as mentioned above.**

**Start command**: /usr/bin/connect-mirror-maker.sh connect-mirror-maker.properties &

**Verification**: Created one more "test2" topic on source cluster, produced data to topic on source cluster and ran consumer on target-cluster(b),topic "a.test2" to verify data replication.

**Observation**: MM2 was able to replicate the topic on the target cluster, a.test2 was present on target cluster b but consumer didn't get any record to consume.

On newer mirror-maker 2.0 instance logs, after topic replication, mirror-sourceconnector task had not restarted which was restarting in single instance after topic replication.

NOTE: There were no error logs seen.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same behavior, your messages are most likely replicated, you can verify this by checking your consumer group offset, the problem is most likely your lag offset is 0 meaning your consumer assumes all previous messages have been consumed. You can reset the offset or read from beginning.
Ideally, the checkpoint heartbeat should contain the latest offset but I currently find this to be empty even though starting with Kafka 2.7, checkpoint heartbeat replication should be automatic